# Google Docs Spreadsheet - Parse Error

Tags: google-sheets

Not sure why this formula does not work. I just want the value to be zero if 60-D15 is negative

```
=MAX(60-D15,0)
```

also tried

```
=MAX(D15,0)
=MAXA(D15,0)
```

Any clues?

Comment: I've tried your approach: `=MAX(60-B1, 0)` and it works as it supposed to. See my file: http://goo.gl/3R5w5

Comment: How does it 'not work'? E.g., what is the result of the formula in your spreadsheet?

Comment: Spreadsheet is in German locale (file, spreadsheet settings). The formula does work in UK locale. The result is #ERROR! ("Parse Error")

Comment: Then you can try: `=MAX(60-B1;0)`, Sorry didn't you own answer allready, that's the solution....

Answer (score 4):

German locale requires a **;** instead of **,** as the argument separator in functions.