# Is Google Sheets' CHOOSE function different from Excel's?

Tags: google-sheets

I need to select randomly between two strings, say `one` and `two`.

I do `=CHOOSE(RANDBETWEEN(1,2), "one", "two")`

It doesn't work and neither does:

`=CHOOSE(1, "one", "two")`

It shows `#ERROR!`.

Comment: Have you tried a semicolon in stead of a comma?

Comment: It should work, see: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/44719/29140

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both formula's work as intended, see screenshot.

### Screenshot

[image]

### Note

As mentioned in my comment, the `CHOOSE` formula is present in Excel and Google Sheets.
You need to use a semicolon in stead of a comma.

### Example

I've created an example file for you: **[CHOOSE](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1g2Y15BP1Ad-48JLU7kTorvsP4bd81csMJfBUB1UNy8o/edit?usp=sharing)**

### Reference

- [Locale Example](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/37818/29140)
- [Excel vs. Google Spreadsheets (old)](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/44719/29140)

Comment: Thanks. It worked using `;` everywhere.

Answer (score 1):

The syntax and effect of CHOOSE is exactly the same for Google Spreadsheets as for Excel. However, I suspect your locale for the sheet in which your formulae are not working has been set to Spain. In that case (and indeed for certain other locales) the required delimiter for the parameters is `;` rather than `,`. Hence I believe @Jacob Jan Tuinstra’s solution should work for you in the sheet where you were experiencing errors.

However, you might want to consider an alternative solution if regularly switching between Excel with `,` and Google Spreadsheets with `;` or because you are more familiar with the comma version but are temporarily working with a spreadsheet created by someone applying the semicolon version.

To change the locale for a spreadsheet to one, say USA, where Google Spreadsheets requires `,` click on File, Spreadsheet settings…, click the top box and select country or country/language of your choice. Valid formulae already existing in a sheet whose locale is changed should automatically acquire the revised delimiter.

Comment: Thanks for help. However, it didn't work using `;`. Also, it shows and error when trying changing the locale setting. I select USA and it returns "File not available ..refresh"

Comment: oh, solved. I had to also change comma to semicolon inside RANDBETWEEN() function, not just CHOOSE one. It doesn't let me change locale setting although.